# Is there a way to set a permanent SHA-1 key for android studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-platform, sha1

I made this Android app that fetches some data using AI Platform Training & Prediction API from Google Cloud Platform. For this app to work it needs to be approved by GCP using SHA-1 Fingerprint certificate. I am making this app as an assessment for module Im taking at the university, so, when the teacher will open my Android Studio project it will have a different SHA-1, so the app will not fetch the data...

Any Ideas how I might be able to maybe set a permanent SHA-1 key for my project, so when the teacher will open the project, Android Studio will not generate a new one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The SHA-1 is based on the app signature. Since this is for a project I suggest you do the following (never do this in a production app).

1. Create a new signing key (Build -> Generate Signed Apk -> APK ->
   Create New)
2. Move the signing key to your project's folder
3. Add this to your app.gradle

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug{
            storeFile file("your_key.keystore")
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("your_key.keystore")
            storePassword 'password'
            keyAlias 'alias'
            keyPassword 'password'
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention, run the signingReport gradle task after you do this to get your new SHA-1 that you have to add to your project.

Answer (score 0):

after creating the .keystore file and running the report I get the new SHA-1 key, but the build fails. I get this:

```
Entry name 'play-services-ads-identifier.properties' collided
```